# Convert solr curl updateJSON syntax to python using urllib2

Tags: python, curl, solr, urllib2, libcurl

I have been trying to learn Solr4.0, and I am looking at the JSON document update in their  [documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateJSON) which looks like the following:

```
cd example/exampledocs
curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/update/json?commit=true' --data-binary @books.json -H 'Content-type:application/json'
```

It works fine and I can see the updated documents on my solr index. However, I was wondering how I can use this curl command in python via urllib2. So, something like:

```
theurl=r"""http://localhost:8983/solr/update/json?commit=true --data-binary @books.json -H 'Content-type:application/json'"""
import urllib2
import httplib
import cookielib
...use urllib2 to post theurl
```

However, this does not work. It looks like urllib2 does not recognize (such as the `-H` which obviously seems curl specific) the above formed `theurl`. How should one be formatting `theurl` such that I could use it with urllib2?

Comment: can you give the stacktrace?

Comment: So, when I open `http://localhost:8983/solr/update/json?commit=true --data-binary @books.json -H 'Content-type:application/json'` with `urllib2` I get: `urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request` I do not think urllib2 understands this bit: `--data-binary @books.json -H 'Content-type:application/json'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would try

```
import urllib2
with open('books.json', 'rb') as data_file:
    my_data = data_file.read()
req = urllib2.Request(url='http://localhost:8983/solr/update/json?commit=true',
                      data=my_data)
req.add_header('Content-type', 'application/json')
f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
# Begin using data like the following
print f.read()
```

From this you can see that the --data-binary parameter is just data sent to the server like in a `POST` request. When that parameter begins with the @ sign, it means to read data from a file. In this case, it's the file 'books.json'. You also need to send the header (the `-H` parameter of `curl`). So you only need to call the `add_header` method with the header name and its value.

Hope that gets you started. More info about urllib2 can be found at http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html

Comment: I think this is close, but I now get 500 error: `urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: Server Error` traceback is on:http://dpaste.com/1025608/ I am sure it is something to do with the format of the url post.

Comment: Thanks so much this. I have been trying this for the past 3 hours but no success. strange that there is no proper python lib for curl to which I can just pass these parameters.

Comment: Ok, I fixed the example... give it a whirl. Since I don't have that solr server installed, I can't test this on my system right now.

Comment: That is simply awesome - It works straight. Thanks so much again. I have accepted your answer now..

Answer (score 0):

Because urllib2 is not available in Python 3.x I offer this alternative.
This code snippet worked for me using Python 3.3 and the excellent [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/) library

```
 import requests

 def postXml(host, xmlFile):
     url = "http://%s:8983/solr/update" % host
     headers = {"content-type" : "text/xml" }
     params = {"commit" : "false" }
     payload = open(xmlFile, "rb").read()
     r = requests.post(url, data=payload, params=params,  headers=headers)
     print("got back: %s" % r.text)
```